# Callback in C++

Tags: c++, callback, emscripten

I am working on a wasm project where I need to define a empscripten fetch callback in a C++ header file, because I need to update a member variable.
Can someone help me with how I define a callback function i C++, where I am able to update a local member variable?

In MyClass.CPP do I have the following method

```
void MyClass::Register()
{
    emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
    emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
    attr.onsuccess = DownloadSucceeded;
    attr.onerror = DownloadFailed;
}
```

I have defined `DownloadSucceeded` and `DownloadFailed` in my header file.

```
void DownloadSucceeded(emscripten_fetch_t* fetch)
{
    printf("Finished downloading %llu bytes from URL %s.\n", fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
    m_unlocked = true;
}

void DownloadFailed(emscripten_fetch_t* fetch)
{
    printf("Downloading %s failed, HTTP failure status code: %d.\n", fetch->url, fetch->status);
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Also free data on failure.
    m_unlocked = false;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
reference to non-static member function must be called
```

From the above exception I tried to send a reference instead, but that didn't seem to work either. If some clever guy can explain why and how to solve this I would be grateful!

My naive reference example which does not work either:

```
attr.onsuccess = &DetectorBridge::DownloadSucceeded;
```

Gives:

```
assigning to 'void (*)(struct emscripten_fetch_t *)' from incompatible type 'void (mynamespace::MyClass::*)(emscripten_fetch_t *)'
```

Comment: @john huh? It has `void *userData` member.

Comment: @273K Yes, I realise that now. It fooled me because the usual practise would be to put the user data pointer directly in the callback signature. I checked the emscriptem source and realised my mistake.

Comment: No. I'm simply just trying to update `m_locked` from the callback.
Not sure where you get the `*void userData` from my question?

Comment: @DNRN `userData` is the solution to your problem.

Comment: `emscripten` requires C-style callbacks. You cannot pass a non-static member function as a C-style callback.

Comment: Side note - don't define functions in header files unless they are `inline`.

Comment: Thanks. I normally implement them in the cpp file, but somehow these two flowed to the header..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the emscriptem source it seems you need to do something like this, where you save your `MyClass` pointer to a field that emscriptem has designed for this purpose.

```
void MyClass::Register()
{
    emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
    emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
    attr.onsuccess = DownloadSucceeded;
    attr.onerror = DownloadFailed;
    attr.userData = this; // save this object
}
```

Then when you get the callback use that saved pointer to modify your variables

```
void DownloadSucceeded(emscripten_fetch_t* fetch)
{
    printf("Finished downloading %llu bytes from URL %s.\n", 
        fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);
    static_cast<MyClass*>(fetch->userData)->m_unlocked = true; // get saved object
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
}
```

I'm ignoring the issue of access to the `m_unlocked` member variable, but if that is an issue there are the usual solutions.

Comment: You need `DownloadSucceeded` to be a static member or a non-member function.